# Vue 3.3.2 not showing warnings on console

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue v3.3.2 , I use it with laravel, vite and inertiajs,
the whole app runs in laravel sail,

it was ok , but sudenly, it stops showing warnings in the console, it shows only errors,

so I can do this :
`{{ someVariable }}` , and it doesn't throw a warning , it doesn't throw anything basically,

this is my app.js file :

```
import useDispatch from "./Composables/dispatcher";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import Toast from "vue-toastification";
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import "../css/app.css";
import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css";

createInertiaApp({
    progress: {
        color: "#E53935",
        delay: 100,
    },

    resolve: (name) => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob("./Pages/**/*.vue", { eager: true });
        return pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`];
    },

    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        const app = createApp({
            render: () => h(App, props),
        });
        app.use(Toast, {
            position: "top-right",
            timeout: 5000,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnFocusLoss: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            draggablePercent: 0.6,
            showCloseButtonOnHover: false,
            hideProgressBar: true,
            closeButton: "button",
            icon: true,
            rtl: false,
        });

        app.use(plugin);
        app.config.globalProperties.$route = route;
        app.config.globalProperties.$dispatch = useDispatch;
        app.mount(el);
    },
});
```

even props validation not working

I to rerun npm couple of times, removed the public/build directory , and still not working

Comment: Where do you expect a warning? during build? or while running? in the browser?

Comment: i used to have a warnings on console during developement, they help catch some issues like when i pass invalid prop type to a component or when using undefined variable on a moustash like this : `{{ undefinedVariable }}`

Comment: Did you change your log levels in chrome? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/log/#filter

Comment: Yep, I enabled all the options, [errors, warnings, verbose , info] , 

it was working before, after few hours , it stoped showing warnings

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Just noticed it yesterday that no warnings were being shown when I forgot to import a component. Do you happen to be using Quasar? I'm using Quasar but the problem happens only when I upgraded from Vue 3.2.47 to 3.3.2 in my Quasar project.

Comment: @Gabe I reset my Chrome dev console settings thinking that might be the problem but it wasn't. I can confirm that this happens on the 3.3. upgrade in my project. I rolled back to 3.2 and the warnings appear again.

Comment: Yep , that is what I did, I just reverted to vue 3.2.25 and warnings start showing, its an issue with v3.3, and don't know if its a feature or bug, because they don't mention anything about it in the release notes